# Deny drop permissions for all other users except actual administrator - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database "myDB" running in a Windows Server machine. Users (coming under Administrators group) remotely access this server and log-in to this database using Windows Authentication mechanism.

I want to deny the drop object permissions for all these users, except for the actual Administrator in this machine

P.S - All the users whose drop permission is to be revoked comes under the Administrators user group.

Comment: You are limited in because they are admins. You should separate groups in AD first and do it properly end to end

Answer (score 1):

Use a DDL trigger to prevent the drop if the login name doesn't match what you expect. Modify the database name and login name as appropriate.

```
USE myDB
GO

CREATE TRIGGER no_drop ON DATABASE FOR DROP_TABLE
AS
IF SUSER_SNAME() != 'DOMAIN\username'
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('No table dropping.', 16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Being admins, they could just disable or alter the DDL trigger once they spot it.

Comment: Naturally. And if you don't trust them to not skirt the safety checks, then they shouldn't be administrators in the first place.

Comment: :)  Being a SQL Server developer myself, I can't count the number of times I have had to skirt the safety checks put in place by the DBAs in order to get my job done.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate the code to revoke DELETE permissions, which includes drop object permissions.  You will need to add your own filtering to make it work in your environment.  TEST THIS IN A TEST ENVIRONMENT FIRST!

```
USE [myDB];
GO

SELECT DISTINCT
    'REVOKE ' + 
    [dperm].[permission_name] COLLATE database_default + 
    ' ON [' + 
    [s].[name] + 
    '].[' + 
    [o].[name] + 
    '] TO [' + 
    [dp].[name] +
    '];' AS [sql_statement]
FROM [sys].[database_principals] AS [dp]

    INNER JOIN [sys].[database_permissions] AS [dperm]
        ON [dp].[principal_id] = [dperm].[grantee_principal_id]

        INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] AS [o]
            ON [dperm].[major_id] = [o].[object_id]

            INNER JOIN [sys].[schemas] AS [s]
                ON [o].[schema_id] = [s].[schema_id]

        LEFT OUTER JOIN [sys].[columns] AS [c]
            ON [dperm].[major_id] = [c].[object_id]
            AND [dperm].[minor_id] = [c].[column_id]

WHERE [dp].[name] <> 'Administrator'  --Change this to reflect your Administrator
AND [dperm].[state] = 'G'
AND [dperm].[type] = 'DL'
```

Hope this helps,

Matt